# Boton HTML que comunica con java para cargar otro archivo HTML en el mismo webView

Tags: javascript, java, html, android-studio, webview

Tengo un activity que carga un webview que ocupa la pantalla entera, y ese webView carga un archivo html que contiene botones que comunican con java mediante JavascriptInterface.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculadora);

    //--------------------------------------------
    //busco los componentes por su id
    final WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //-----------------------------------------------------

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//abilito javascript
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//abilito el zoom


    webView.loadUrl("file:///data/data/com.example.mecamismos/files/mecanismo.html");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, datos), "Android");
```

Dentro de la clase webAppInterface quiero que al pulsar el boton html me cambie la pagina web, pero no consigo importar el webView a una clase que no sea activity

```
public class WebAppInterface{
private Context mContext;
private boolean eligeweb = true;


WebAppInterface(Context c, ArrayList<String> d) {
    mContext = c;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void verHTML() {
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if (eligeweb) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///data/data/com.example.mecamismos/files/mecanismo1.html");
        eligeweb = false;
    } else {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///data/data/com.example.mecamismos/files/mecanismo.html");
        eligeweb = true;
    }
}
```

Alguna idea de como cargar otra pagina web desde un boton html que comunique con java, y tambien me gustaria crear otro boton html que cambie de activity.

Answer (score 0):

Para navegar entre páginas dentro de un mismo webView no hace falta comunicar con java, solo hace falta poner un botón que vincule la dirección donde esta la página web a la que quieres que te envie. Además, aunque la segunda pagina web este guardada en la memoria interna, y no haga falta uso de internet para acceder a ella, para que funcione el vinculo hace falta habilitar el uso de internet en el archivo manifest.

Abrimos el archivo AndroidManifest.xml y escribimos esto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```